ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings correct registry syntax for intranet URLs
I created a GPO to avoid blocking xlsx files to be downloaded from our intranet site.
policy is readed and applied to the clients and the registry created the key REG_SZ called "ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings" under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge". The value of the ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings is:

{"domains": ["http://bi.contoso.local:8080",
"contoso.local"], "file_extension": "xlsx"}

BUT edge://policy/ has no policy applied and the policy don't works.
What am I doing wrong?

I just tested this policy on my own device, and you have almost everything configured correctly, the reason you don't see the "ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings" policy at "edge://policy" is because your values are set wrong - it's just short A pair of "[ ]". The correct values are as follows:
[{"domains": ["http://bi.contoso.local:8080", "contoso.local"], "file_extension": "xlsx"}]

You can also refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#exemptfiletypedownloadwarnings.
